# spring security oauth2 Authorization Basic preflight error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a problem with spring security oauth2. I have everything working as expected except for CORS when having HTTP Basic Authorization. When Basic Auth is loaded, browser sends OPTIONS request to my endpoint. However, I get an error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my code (I am using Annotations):

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/*" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
       CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
       encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
       encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
       return new Filter[]{encodingFilter,
               new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"),
               new CORSFilter() };
    } 
}

// CORS

public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            System.out.println("Filtering on...........................................................");
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }

}
```

OAuth2ServerConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // other stuff...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/**", "/kiosks").permitAll().and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Every other basic HTTP requests work (by basic I mean the ones that don't need preflight OPTIONS requests). CORS is allowed as any other. Basic Auth ones don't work though.

I want to mention that I have tested every type of solution (from Google and StackOverflow) to make this thing work but I have not even gotten close to fixing the problem.

What am I missing here?